# PyQt / Qt setStyleSheet. How to not display border around background image

Tags: qt, layout, background-image

---

Hello Overflowers,

I was going to ask you a question. However during writing it I found solution. So I just want to share with you with it.

My issue was that I couldn't figure out how to not the display these awful margins / borders while seting up background image in PyQt application.

I was using style sheet

```
        style = """QFrame{
border-image: url(back.gif) ;;
border: 0px;
outline: 0px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px; }"""
app.setStyleSheet(style)
app.show()
```

and even after that there was 10pixels of border around image

The problem was that i was using QStackedWidget() and layouts:

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.stack)
        self.mainMenu_form = MainMenuForm(self)
        self.config_form = ConfigurationForm(self)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.mainMenu_form)
```

And the solution Was to add one line for layout properties:

```
layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
```

I've wasted a lot of hours for this problem, hope someone after reading this post will not

Answer (score 1):

Answer already in the question:

try:

```
layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
```